# read an array of pixel values python

Tags: python, image

I would like to take a screenshot with a certain range of the screen, and then I would like to check the pixel values of certain lines (eg x_axis from 400 to 800).
I tried multiple ways like the imagegrab, gdi32.GetPixel and some more. It seems reading pixels values take a lot of time, so I even tried converting it into a list, something like this

```
im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
pixels = list(im .getdata())
```

Even this does not seem fast. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`ImageGrab` returns pixels in PIL format (the Python Imaging Library: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm), and `.getdata()` already returns the pixels as a sequence. By wrapping it in `list()` again you are doing the same (expensive) operation twice. You can just do:

```
im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
pixels = im.getdata()
```

And iterate through your pixels in your favorite way.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot.... but could you let me know if I use this for color in im.getdata(): how can I iterate in such a way that I only check every one pixel out of three

Comment: Do you mean you want to to process a pixel, then not process 2, then process a pixel, not process 2, etc?

Comment: What about this:
`for index, pixel in enumerate(pixels):
    if index % 3 == 0:
        # do something`?